# What are algorithm family do iterative sampling methods fall into?

Tags: algorithm, sampling

I am developing an algorithm that samples 100 points from the dataset. Computes the average of those 100 points. Then re-samples 100 points from the dataset and updates the running average. This process keeps on going until convergence.

What "kind" of algorithm is this called? I know that it's not divide-and-conquer because divide-and-conquer has a recursive component to it. Is it just an iterative method? Is there something more appropriate to call it?

Comment: A running average is also known as a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average), or rolling average. But it's not clear what you mean by "samples 100 points from the dataset" and "re-samples 100 points from the dataset". Moving averages typically work on sequential samples equally spaced in time.